# How to recover from a bad upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, parallels

I have 3 computers, 2 running Ubuntu under VMWare Fusion, 1 under Parallels. The 2 VMWare computers upgraded to 14.04.01 fine, but the Parallels one complains that it cannot set the display resolution, and that it cannot mount /media/psf. I tried a lot of different methods of booting, but everything is unresponsive, and in fact the destop doesn't finish displaying the menu bar nor the icon strip or anything for that matter.

How do I recover?
Can I preserve the files that I have?

Comment: Don't worry about the files. A boot failure does not mean you can't recover the data if needed. Have you tried booting in recovery mode? Does it work or does it give an error?

Comment: It boots but is unresponsive. I am going to see if I can boot and install from the ISO.

Comment: Tried true amd64+mac install, but it is 10.04 not 14.04.01 so did not have the option of reinstalling. It only offered the options of wiping out all my files or installing 14.04 alongside 14.04.01. So now am burning a second DVD, the 14.04.1 AMD64-iso, hoping that it will work.

Comment: Unfortunately, the 14.04.1 AMD64-iso DVD didn't offer a reinstall option either. :-( I came across this page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation, and am trying it. It says that it will wipe out files in /usr. Sigh. Luckily I have the other Ubuntu machines that I can transfer my files from.

Comment: This is not the first time that a live upgrade yielded an unbootable system. Please add a "reinstall" option in the installer.

Comment: From the live DVD you can backup everything, so that shouldn't be a big problem if you don't mind spending the time of copying the data back in place after the reinstallation. Moreover, if you have a separate `/home` partition, most data would not be overwritten at all.